# How can I update state in two separate components using a custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a custom hook to be able to open and close a pop-out menu with conditional rendering using style `display: none` and `display:block`. I think I understand how to share the state between the components (I can console log that and get that working) , but I can not figure out how to **update** the state using the hook.

I am certain that I have some fundamental misunderstanding here but if anyone can clarify what it is I am trying to achieve that would be **awesome!** I have tried to learn this for several nights and here is where I have got to.

This is the header of the pop out menu it only contains a close button at the moment

```
import React from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faWindowClose } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import useOpenCloseElementMenu from '../Hooks/openCloseElementMenu'

function ElementMenuHeader() {
const { elementMenuOpenClose, setElementMenuOpenClose } = useOpenCloseElementMenu();
return (
    <div id="App-Close-Element-Menu-Container">
    <button id="App-Close-Element-Menu"
        onClick={() => setElementMenuOpenClose(false) }
    >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faWindowClose} />
    </button>
    </div>
);
}

export default ElementMenuHeader
```

This is the pop out menu

```
import React from 'react';
import SizerGroup from '../Sizer/sizerGroup';
import './element-menu.css';
import ElementMenuHeader from './element-menu-header';
import TitleWithLine from './title-with-line';
import TypeSelector from './type-selector';
import TemplateSelector from './template-selector';
import useOpenCloseElementMenu from '../Hooks/openCloseElementMenu'

function Editor(props) {
const { elementMenuOpenClose, setElementMenuOpenClose } = useOpenCloseElementMenu();
console.log(elementMenuOpenClose);
return (
    <div className="App-Element-Menu"  
    style={{display: elementMenuOpenClose ? 'block' : 'none' }}
    >
    <ElementMenuHeader />
    <TitleWithLine title="Element size" />
    <SizerGroup />
    <TitleWithLine title="Elements" />
    <TypeSelector />
    <TitleWithLine title="Templates" />
    <TemplateSelector />
    </div>
);
}

export default Editor
```

This is the toolbar that has the open menu button

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from '../Button/button'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faBoxes } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import './toolbar.css'
import useOpenCloseElementMenu from '../Hooks/openCloseElementMenu'


function Toolbar(props) {
const { toolbar_show_or_hide } = props
const elementMenuIcon = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={ faBoxes } />
const { elementMenuOpenClose, setElementMenuOpenClose } = useOpenCloseElementMenu();
const openEditor = setElementMenuOpenClose[true]

return (
<div className="App-Toolbar" style={{ display: toolbar_show_or_hide  ? "flex" : "none" }} >
    <Button
    id="App-Open-Element-Menu-Button"
    icon={ elementMenuIcon }
    useToolTip={ true }
    toolTipText="Elements menu. Select elements to populate the theme."
    buttonFunction={ openEditor }
    />
    </div>
)
}

export default Toolbar
```

This is the hook

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const useOpenCloseElementMenu = () => {
const [elementMenuOpenClose, setElementMenuOpenClose] = useState(false);
return { elementMenuOpenClose, setElementMenuOpenClose };
};

export default useOpenCloseElementMenu;
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel you donot have to pass the hook in a separate function, useOpenCloseElementMenu, like you did.

Instead of importing the `../Hooks/openCloseElementMenu` function thing,

I'd rather just call the hooks directly instead as

`const [elementMenuOpenClose, setElementMenuOpenClose] = useState(false);`

in the editor and toolbar component in place of `const { elementMenuOpenClose, setElementMenuOpenClose } = useOpenCloseElementMenu();`.

Also which component did you use the toolbar component if I may ask? Because I don't seem to see any of that here...It confusing where it got the `toolbar_show...` props from.

{**I hope this helps cause that seem like the most obvious reason**}

Comment: I feel like I need the "setter" so to speak, in a separate file since the toolbar has a button to open the menu and the menu has a button to close itself. The buttons for open and close are in two different components. I need to be able to share the logic across the toolbar and the menu I feel.